# Conflict when using both java.endorsed.dirs and java.library.path

Tags: java, worldwind

I have an existing java application that utilizes CORBA.  As a result, it uses the **java.endorsed.dirs** command line parameter to point to the directory that contains the CORBA libraries we are using.  The application is currently running just fine with the following command line:

```
java -splash:images/logo.png -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=./lib -jar "myapp.jar"
```

Now, I need to add WorldWind support to my application.  The WorldWind jar files call native libraries and seem to direct me to using the **java.library.path** command line parameter to point to the directory that contains the native libraries.  When I use the following command line (add the java.library.path):

```
java -splash:images/logo.png -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=./lib -Djava.library.path="./lib" -jar "myapp.jar"
```

I receive the following error when I run my application:

```
..Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gluegen-rt in java.library.path
```

"gluegen-rt" is one of the libraries that WorldWind uses. The exception above is saying that it is having a hard time finding WorldWind libraries

If I remove the java.endorsed.dirs directory from the command line

```
java -splash:images/logo.png -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Djava.library.path="./lib" -jar "myapp.jar"
```

... then my application runs fine(except that it is now using the default CORBA implementation and not the one that ships with our product).

The only link I could find on this topic is [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1540135&tstart=240), but that question did not seem to get answered, so I thought I would ask here.

Can these two command line parameters co-exist?  If not, is there a work around?

**Note:** I am running this on Red Hat Linux.  Based on a comment I received, I did try setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running my app.  That did not make any difference.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:./lib
```

**Note:** It is not possible based on end user setup to put our CORBA files in the standard jre /endorsed directory.

**Note:** I don't think this question is specific to CORBA or WorldWind, but I wanted to give the reasons that I am using both of the aforementioned command line parameters.

Comment: can you show your command line?

Comment: is "gluegen-rt" something related to this (corba/worldwind) or some system file?

Comment: this seems like linux or similar.  did you try adding "lib" to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH before executing your app?

Comment: probably irrelevant, but that should probably be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:./lib"`

Comment: Updated my question with responses to @jtahlborn questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a work around for my particular situation.  Both command line parameters (java.endorsed.dirs and java.library.path) were pointing to the same directory.  Things began to work when I changed them to point to different directories.  I ended up moving the WorldWind libraries to lib/worldwind so that my command line looked like this:

```
java -splash:images/logo.png -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -Djava.endorsed.dirs=./lib -Djava.library.path="./lib/worldwind" -jar "myapp.jar"
```

I  hope this helps someone else with this problem.  Although I am still not sure why there was a "conflict" in the first place.